# Bash script to list files not found

Tags: bash

I have been looking for a way to list file that do not exist from a list of files that are required to exist.  The files can exist in more than one location. What I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash
fileslist="$1"
while read fn
do
  if [ ! -f `find . -type f -name $fn ` ];
  then
   echo $fn
  fi
done < $fileslist
```

If a file does not exist the find command will not print anything and the test does not work.  Removing the not and creating an if then else condition does not resolve the problem.

How can i print the filenames that are not found from a list of file names?

New script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fileslist="$1"
foundfiles="~/tmp/tmp`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.txt"
touch $foundfiles
while read fn
do
  `find . -type f -name $fn | sed 's:./.*/::' >> $foundfiles`
done < $fileslist
cat $fileslist $foundfiles | sort | uniq -u
rm $foundfiles
```

Comment: Find what you can and diff with the list you expect?

Comment: @cdeszaq, the first thing I thought of, but couldn't come up with the way of doing it without temporary files or sheer bashisms :)

Comment: Currently I create a list of what i can find and diff that with the fileslist.  I thought that I might be able to automate this some to create a list of files that I have to work on.

Comment: maybe find is not the right tool. Is there some alternative that I have not thought of?

Comment: I tested my original script on fedora 16 at home and it appears to work how I wanted it to. I was working on RHEL 5.7 at work. This makes me think that some of the answers that were posted that didn't work for me may be valid for others.

Comment: I have changed my attack some. I don't think that I can get the version of find that I have to behave the way that I want so I save the results: `find . -type f -name $fn | sed 's:./.*/::' >> $foundfiles`. Outside of the loop `cat $fileslist $foundfiles | sort | uniq -u `.  This may not be the most eligant of solutions but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing body with `[[ -z "$(find . -type f -name $fn)" ]] && echo $fn`. (note that this code is bound to have problems with filenames containing spaces).

More efficient bashism:

```
diff <(sort $fileslist|uniq) <(find . -type f -printf %f\\n|sort|uniq)
```

I think you can handle diff output.

Comment: Neither -z nor ! -n work with the result of find when it does not match a file name.

Comment: Works for me `$ [[ -z "$(find /tmp -name nosuchfile)" ]] && echo no such thing in there
no such thing in there`

Comment: I've added more efficient diffing. Since you're diffing now, I think you can properly tweak diff options and know what to do with the output

Answer (score 1):

Here is test.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

fn=test.bash

exists=`find . -type f -name $fn`
if [ -n "$exists" ]
then
  echo Found it
fi
```

It sets $exists = to the result of the find. the if -n checks if the result is not null.

Comment: If $exists is null, then you'll get a syntax error on the 'if' statement.

Comment: I tested this code with a file that existed, and one that didn't. It worked fine.

Comment: Neither -z nor ! -n work with the result of find when it does not match a file name.

Comment: Sorry, I had it backward. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
fileslist="$1"
while read fn
do
  FPATH=`find . -type f -name $fn`
  if [ "$FPATH." = "." ]
  then
   echo $fn
  fi
done < $fileslist
```

You were close!

Comment: This raises the question of what find returns when it doesn't find a match. How can I evaluate the result?

Comment: The exit code from `find` will be false when it fails. So you could simply `find . -name "$fn" >/dev/null || echo Not there: "$fn"`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
find -type f -print0 | grep -Fzxvf - requiredfiles.txt
```

The `-print0` and `-z` protect against filenames which contain newlines. If your utilities don't have these options and your filenames don't contain newlines, you should be OK.

Comment: i like the idea but i don't think the -v option works like that

Comment: got this working well will with a bash loop and grep -Fzqa. it's also pretty quick with 10K files

Answer (score 0):

The repeated `find` to filter one file at a time is very expensive. If your file list is directly compatible with the output from `find`, run a single `find` and remove any matches from your list:

```
find . -type f |
fgrep -vxf - "$1"
```

If not, maybe you can massage the output from `find` in the pipeline before the `fgrep` so that it matches the format in your file; or, conversely, massage the data in your file into `find`-compatible.

Comment: I am looking for 20 or 100 files but the directory structure that I am looking in has almost 1500 files. I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script and it works for me

```
#!/bin/bash
fileslist="$1"
found="Found:"
notfound="Not found:"
len=`cat $1 | wc -l`
n=0;

while read fn
do
  # don't worry about this, i use it to display the file list progress
  n=$((n + 1))
  echo -en  "\rLooking $(echo "scale=0; $n * 100 / $len" | bc)% "
  if [ $(find / -name $fn | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
  then
    found=$(printf "$found\n\t$fn")
  else
    notfound=$(printf "$notfound\n\t$fn")
  fi
done < $fileslist

printf "\n$found\n$notfound\n"
```

The line counts the number of lines and if its greater than 0 the find was a success. This searches everything on the hdd. You could replace / with . for just the current directory.

```
$(find / -name $fn | wc -l) -gt 0
```

Then i simply run it with the files in the files list being separated by newline

```
./search.sh files.list
```